# Why does visual studio ask give option to discard in-memory changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

When I save a solution that I have actually not made any changes to, I often get a dialog that tells me "Checking out without saving will cause you to lose your in-memory changes".  It gives me a few options, Discard In-Memory changes, Check-Out, Cancel, and Save-As. Is there way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Drop VSS. Sorry for the not-wanted answer, but VSS is crap. (Oh, and, while I liked the IDE, I never liked VCS to be integrated in it. But that's subjective. The other advice, however unwelcome, isn't.)

Comment: You might want to consider a more robust source control system such as CVS, SVN or Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent this happening is not to start modifying the code before you check-out the file.

Comment: The only way to modify the code is to check it out, but this happens when you don't modify the code and just click the save button.  There is no reason to hit save, but if you do anyway, it happens.  I believe it also happens if you build too.